# Is it safe to register a BroadcastRegister in the Application class?

Tags: android

Registering a BroadcastReceiver in the application class has a lot of advantages: it is a central point of control and it avoids registering various receivers in Activities. But the problem is that I have not found a way to unregister the receiver as there is no onDestroy in the Application class.

Comment: The `Application` object lives until the process is terminated.

Comment: So I can leave the BroadcastReceiver there, without unregistering it?

Comment: @Vannen  no it is recommended that unregister your broadcast somewhere( that most of the time it would be better to unregister your broadcast in onfinish function)

Comment: "So I can leave the BroadcastReceiver there, without unregistering it?" -- only if you are supposed to be receiving broadcasts during the entire lifetime of your process.

Comment: @pooyan There is no onFinish method in the Application class.

Comment: @Vannen I mean onfinsh function of your activities or other thing like this.